# How to solve Listner error in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
LSNRCTL> status
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   32-bit Windows Error: 2: No such file or directory
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MD-TRNGEUP55.Virtusa.com
)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00515: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
   32-bit Windows Error: 1001: Unknown error
LSNRCTL>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the FAQ, and try to format your question in a sensible way (I did it this time for you). Also, your question lacks a *lot* of necessary information - whether you can ping the database server, whether DNS lookup works, whether the listener is actually running, whether you can connect locally ...

Comment: You can delete the listener (Network Configuration Assistant), create a new one and then run DBCA (Database Configuration Assistant) and assign the new listener with your database.